# How can I score an assessment in Google Sheets where the answers to each question are weighted differently?

Tags: google-sheets

I want to make an assessment tool in Google Sheets that asks a bunch of questions and provides a score. Each question has a set of possible answers, so they're all multiple choice. But each of the possible answers adjusts the score in a different way on a per-question basis.

Here's an [example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/190ufw2FB53t3rWTq3FVHxl6ms9KI5TKUc03QDOnwJG8/edit?usp=sharing) with two tabs, one for the questions and one for the answer weights. The challenge I have is what to put in cells D2 and D3.

For example, "yes" might be worth +10 points on one question and -5 points on another. Similarly, one question may allow "yes"/"no"/"I'm not sure" and another may allow "yes"/"sometimes"/"no".

I'm not sure if Google Sheets contains the tools that'll let me do this in a reasonable way without resorting to writing App Script. It looks `SWITCH` might be useful, but I'm not clear on exactly how to wire things together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following [INDEX](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242?hl=en&authuser=0) and [MATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378?hl=en&authuser=0) formula:

```
=INDEX('answer-scoring'!$A:$G,
 MATCH($A2,'answer-scoring'!$A:$A,0),
 MATCH($C2,'answer-scoring'!$A$1:$G$1,0))
```

where index returns values from score table that matches both question and answer.

You can find it [Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bhbne0gyZaD-YRDoJKAfMnDkzwZ5ZTpqk-oOPPzYLgM/edit#gid=0)